# Why Indonesia-citizens and not Indonesian-citizens?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The tag [indonesia-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indonesia-citizens) has the country name, not the demonym which is the case in all the citizens tags (except US, UK and EU). For example, [nicaraguan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaraguan-citizens), [indian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-citizens) and [australian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-citizens).

I think the tag should be changed to [indonesian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indonesian-citizens). Right?

Comment: This came up before. It doesn't really matter because for some country names there's not an adjective form (New Zealand for instance) and for others it might be quite long compared to the noun. The logic at the time was that the "shortest unambiguous" variant would be OK.

Comment: **[country-citizen tags - convention needed](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/344)**

Comment: @hippietrail Except in this case there IS an adjective form. Perhaps it was misspelt and never got noticed till now?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee exactly..

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Could well be. I was just saying that to me it doesn't really matter. Change it or not change it. We already have both kinds of `*-citizen` tags.

Comment: @hippietrail not true, there are exceptions in some obvious cases such as US, NZ, EU and UK. Can you bring more examples where the country name is used instead of the demonym? UK, US, NZ and EU are really logical when tagged using the abbreviation but when using a full name I do not see the logic in using _Nicaraguan_ but not using _Indonesian_.

Comment: As I keep saying, it doesn't matter to me and this discussion has taken place before. We've got a lot worse tagging problems than this if anybody is feeling tagging to be important at the moment.

Comment: I want that `n` letter to be added to the `Indonesia-citizens` tag so I can die in peace...

Comment: The CIA World Factbook lists nouns and adjective for countries, which would make it *Indonesian* : https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2110.html

Comment: Ankur has a ♦ so he can just change it if he wants d-: And then continue and fix some of the tag problems that matter d-:

Comment: @hippietrail you are right.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee why don't you change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed to [indonesian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indonesian-citizens) now

Comment: Thanks Ankur, you are the best.